# Not showing font awesome icons

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

i'm new here, been redirected here form the support team of font awesome. I have a problem with some icons i have set on a wordpress site, they only appear visible with my wordpress user logged, can't see them on logged out, or even in any other explorers..

i have runed a troubleshoot test and got this link here:

https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css

Anyone may give some light in to this?

Comment: Could you share your website to take a look?

Comment: Font Awesome can be tricky to troubleshoot sometimes. Can you give us some more information on how you're implementing it into your wordpress site, and give us some code examples of how you're calling it in your code?
Are you using any font awesome plugins, or something like the @fortawesome composer package?

Comment: sure! i used the simple code copy paste on this site https://www.digitalhairacademy.com/areaprivadamodulosfdc   i believe i have used this codes <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>,  and since the icons weren't showing i've installed the plugin as suggested by the wordpress template developer. Now i 'm able to see the icons , but only if i have logged in user wordpress, cant see it in anyother devices or explorers

Comment: could i add a screenshoot here to show where the icons are showing on loged in user wordpress??

Comment: here the screenshot of where icons should be https://snipboard.io/Mb0YeL.jpg

Comment: anybody knowing what might cause the visibility problem?